# MySQL function return more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, function

I'd like to write a MySQL stored function that returns multiple rows of data.  Is this possible?  It seems to be locked at 1 row -- can't even return **0** rows.

For example

```
DELIMITER //

create function go()

RETURNS int
deterministic
NO SQL

BEGIN

return null ; -- this doesn't return 0 rows!  it returns 1 row
-- return 0 ;

END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Returning `null` from a MySQL stored proc though, doesn't return 0 rows.. it returns 1 row with the value `null` in it.

Can I return 0, or more than 1 row from a MySQL function, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the MySQL reference:

> 23.4.6:  Can MySQL 5.0 stored routines return result sets?
>
> Stored procedures can, but stored functions cannot. If you perform an ordinary SELECT inside a stored procedure, the result set is returned directly to the client. You need to use the MySQL 4.1 (or above) client-server protocol for this to work. This means that—for instance—in PHP, you need to use the mysqli extension rather than the old mysql extension.

Comment: WoW!   That's really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a function that returns a table:

```
create function go()
RETURNS @MyTable table
```

then populate that table however...

```
Insert @MyTable
Values (.....)
```

and then return that.  It should contain 0, 1, or many rows, depending on whatever you filled it with.  (Or didn't fill it with...)

Comment: That's an interesting approach.  I wonder how expensive this is.

Comment: It's also untested - I'm currently double-checking my approach.  I've done it in other SQL flavors.  Which version of MySQL are you on?

Comment: Not supported by mysql